# arm-none-eabi-g++ compiler throws compilation error pthread_exit was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, debian, cross-compiling

Running in debian linux `arm-none-eabi-g++ pthread.c -o pthread -lpthread` throws below compilation error. But if I run the `g++ pthread.c -o pthread -lpthread` there is no compilation errors. I never used cross compiler. I knew there is problem in linking in libraries. Please help me. I searched lot in the internet but there is no luck.

My `pthread.c` program:

```
include "pthread.h" 
include "stdio.h"
include "stdlib.h"

void *worker_thread(void *arg) 
{ 
    printf("This is worker_thread()\n"); 
    pthread_exit(NULL); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    pthread_t my_thread; 
    int ret; 
    printf("In main: creating thread\n"); 
    ret = pthread_create(&my_thread, NULL, &worker_thread, NULL); 
    if(ret != 0) 
    {
        printf("Error: pthread_create() failed\n"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    pthread_exit(NULL); 
}
```

Compilation error:

```
pthread.c: In function 'void* worker_thread(void*)':

pthread.c:8:18: error: 'pthread_exit' was not declared in this scope
pthread_exit(NULL);
                  ^
pthread.c: In function 'int main()':
pthread.c:15:1: error: 'pthread_t' was not declared in this scope
 pthread_t my_thread;
 ^
pthread.c:15:11: error: expected ';' before 'my_thread'
 pthread_t my_thread;
           ^
pthread.c:18:23: error: 'my_thread' was not declared in this scope
 ret = pthread_create(&my_thread, NULL, &worker_thread, NULL);
                       ^
pthread.c:18:60: error: 'pthread_create' was not declared in this scope
 ret = pthread_create(&my_thread, NULL, &worker_thread, NULL);
                                                            ^
pthread.c:24:21: error: 'pthread_exit' was not declared in this scope
  } pthread_exit(NULL);
```

Comment: And you created a `pthread.h` file by yourself?

Comment: If he did that, then g++ would also give priority to the matching header file in `-I.`. I suppose the problem might be with the `pthread.h` that comes with the arm cross compiler.

Comment: I didn't create the pthread.h. arm-none-eabi-g++ refer the pthread.h file in   # 1 "/usr/include/newlib/pthread.h" 1 3
# 25 "/usr/include/newlib/pthread.h" 3
# 29 "/usr/include/newlib/pthread.h" 2 3
# 427 "/usr/include/newlib/pthread.h" 3

Comment: Do I need to install reinstall arm cross compiler?

Comment: @Raj: See my answer. Reinstalling the arm cross compiler wont help.

Comment: Please quote your entire compiler command-line including all flags. Also please quote your target CPU/MCU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the first three lines in your code are:

```
#include ...
```

And not

```
include ...
```

And you just copy/pasted wrong. Otherwise you are not showing all the errors you got.

---

Other than that.
The problem is most likely due to something weird going on with your `pthread.h` file. Compile your program with the `-E` option (this outputs the result after from the precompiler):

```
 arm-none-eabi-g++ -E pthread.c -o foobar -lpthread
```

Then look at the output file `foobar`, search for `pthread.h`, or just:

```
 grep 'pthread.h' foobar
```

This gives you the full path of the `pthread.h` file that gets included when cross compiling. Compare this to the header file included with the regular `g++` compiler. That might give you a clue as to what is going on. (For instance, if it points you to a local `pthread.h` that you might have created.)

---

For instance, on my system, `g++` finds and the following `pthread.h`:

```
/usr/include/pthread.h
```

While `arm-none-eabi-g++` uses:

```
/usr/include/newlib/pthread.h
```

This `newlib/pthread.h` does not declare any of the `pthread_exit` and `pthread_t`, which is your problem.

---

So, where does this `newlib/pthread.h` come from? With a `apt-file search newlib/pthread.h`, it shows that this is part of the package `libnewlib-dev`, which a `apt-cache show libnewlib-dev` says that this is: `...library intended for use on embedded systems`, which is apparently what the `arm` cross-compiler uses.

---

**So, long story short:** your arm cross-compiler doesn't support threads.

**So, long story, less short:** `arm-none-eabi-g++` doesn't support threading. You can confirm this with how the compiler was was compiled, by calling `arm-none-eabi-g++ -xc -E -v -`. It will output something like

`Configured with: ...blablabla...  --disable-threads`

Are you sure you are targeting the right arm architecture? There are several cross compilers for different arm architectures.

Comment: I missed # symbol while pasting here. That is not the problem. I  tried to compile using -E,  g++ refer /usr/include/pthread.h but arm cross compiler refer /usr/inlcude/newlib/pthread.h. That is the different. Do I need to reinstall anything?

Comment: No, the problem is that the `arm` compiler uses an embedded version of `pthread.h` that needs to be used differently than the regular ones.

Comment: This is what I got root@ie3becccilxagt01:/home/rhel/c# apt-cache show libnewlib-arm-none-eabi
Package: libnewlib-arm-none-eabi
Source: newlib
Version: 2.1.0+git20140818.1a8323b-2
Installed-Size: 118434
Maintainer: Agustin Henze <tin@debian.org>
Architecture: all
Depends: libnewlib-dev
Recommends: gcc-arm-none-eabi, libstdc++-arm-none-eabi-newlib
Suggests: libnewlib-doc

 Newlib is a C library and math library intended for use on embedded systems.

Comment: Perhaps you should read my answer a bit more closely? In any case, `gcc-arm-none-eabi` targets "ARM chips using Cortex-M0/M0+/M3/M4,
 Cortex-R4/R5/R7 and Cortex-A* processors.", and does not support threading. I don't know if it's because these architectures do not support it, or if it is just the compiler. You have to figure that out yourself. If what you instead want is to target a *different* arm architecture, then use the corresponding cross-compiler. For example `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi`.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I understood the problem with compiler. I will try other compilers.